# Is it legal to reuse memory from a fundamental type array for a different (yet still fundamental) type array

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

This is a follow up to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51930334/3545273) about memory re-use. As the original question was about a specific implementation, the answer was related to that specific implementation.

So I wonder whether, it is legal in a conformant implementation to re-use the memory of an array of a fundamental type for an array of a different type provided:

- both types are fundamental type and as such have trivial dtor and default ctor
- both types have same size and alignment requirement

I ended with the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int Size = 10;

void *allocate_buffer() {
    void * buffer = operator new(Size * sizeof(int), std::align_val_t{alignof(int)});
    int *in = reinterpret_cast<int *>(buffer); // Defined behaviour because alignment is ok
    for (int i=0; i<Size; i++) in[i] = i;  // Defined behaviour because int is a fundamental type:
                                           // lifetime starts when is receives a value
    return buffer;
}
int main() {
    void *buffer = allocate_buffer();        // Ok, defined behaviour
    int *in = static_cast<int *>(buffer);    // Defined behaviour since the underlying type is int *
    for(int i=0; i<Size; i++) {
        std::cout << in[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), "Non matching type sizes");
    static_assert(alignof(int) == alignof(float), "Non matching alignments");
    float *out = static_cast<float *>(buffer); //  (question here) Declares a dynamic float array starting at buffer
    // std::cout << out[0];      // UB! object at &out[0] is an int and not a float
    for(int i=0; i<Size; i++) {
        out[i] = static_cast<float>(in[i]) / 2;  // Defined behaviour, after execution buffer will contain floats
                                                 // because float is a fundamental type and memory is re-used.
    }
    // std::cout << in[0];       // UB! lifetime has ended because memory has been reused
    for(int i=0; i<Size; i++) {
        std::cout << out[i] << " ";         // Defined behaviour since the actual object type is float *
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have added comments explaining why I think that this code should have defined behaviour. And IMHO everything is fine and AFAIK standard conformant, but I was not able to find whether the line marked *question here* is or not valid.

Float objects do re-use memory from int objects, so life time of the ints end when life time of the floats start, so the stric-aliasing rule should not be a problem. Array was dynamically allocated so objects (int and floats) are in fact all created in a *void type* array returned by `operator new`. So I think that everything should be ok.

But as it allows for low level object replacement which is normally frowned upon in modern C++ I must acknowledge I have a doubt...

So the question is: does above code invokes UB and if yes where and why?

Disclaimer: I would advise against this code in a portable code base, and this is really a *language lawyer* question.

Comment: The line starts with `float *out = static_cast<float *>(buffer);`. It was by default past the visible part. Edited

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even think to scroll

Comment: Note that objects come into live by being constructed, e.g., a call to `new(addr) T()`. This applies to all types including built-in types. I'm not an expert in that area but I think your code is a violation of the aliasing rules, i.e., undefined behavior.

Comment: This topic is the best way to get headaches and spitting arguments, prepare yourself.

Comment: _"Defined behaviour because int is a fundamental type: lifetime starts when is receives a value"_ is false. The ways to create an object are to either a) declare it b) `new` c) union assignment, which doesn't include assignment. This may be about to change.

Comment: @PasserBy: I assumed that placement new was a no-op for fundamental types. Maybe I have been too optimistic here...

Comment: No-op `new` is kinda like an compiler optimization, `new` _always_ does something in the abstract machine: it creates the object.

Comment: So you have to break your understanding of C++ into pieces.  There is your code, the abstract machine, and the assembly/binary code implementation.  Your code's behavior is described by what the abstract machine does, and in the abstract machine *new is not a noop*, as it creates an object that wasn't there before.  In the actual hardware, *new is often a noop* as there is nothing to do in the hardware.  But the noopness of new in hardware doesn't mean that it isn't required in the abstract machine.

Comment: The working proposal [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) may change the current behavior.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The Standard has been quite specific that types with trivial construction come into existence when storage is obtained; no construction step is necessary.

Comment: @BenVoigt: As xskxzr points out, it's apparently ambiguous. A key motivation for P0593 is that under reasonable interpretations of the C++17, `malloc` fails to construct objects even though is certainly obtains storage. Of course, this is pretty theoretical. No real-world C++ compiler will break `malloc`.

Comment: @xskxzr: I'm sad because all these "fixes" seem to completely overlook the first paragraph of `[basic.life]`

Comment: @BenVoigt: The authors of the C89 Standard didn't think there would be much practical difference between actions where all implementations were required to behave a certain way, and actions where *quality* implementations--at least those targeting most common platforms and application fields--should be expected to behave the same way *even when not required to do so*.  If an action would have a clear and unambiguous meaning which is exploited by code for a particular target platform and application field, people seeking to write quality compilers for that platform and field shouldn't *care*...

Comment: ...about whether the Standard would require them to support the behavior.  The Standard is a bit sloppy in some regards with regard to how objects are created, but for implicit-lifetime objects what they should care about is what references exist and how they're used.  The only way to reconcile that is to recognize that it's possible for multiple objects to identify the same storage, provided that only freshly-derived objects are used for to access the storage or derive other objects.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: C and C++ are generally used to produce programs to run on real machines.  The "abstract machine" model goes back to a time when many real machines' natural behaviors didn't include everything mandated for the abstract one, making it necessary to "emulate" some constructs (e.g. `x<<y` must be supported even on platforms without a left-shift instruction).  The Standard allows conforming compilers to limit useful behaviors to those mandated for the "abstract machine", but it also allows conforming compilers to be of such poor quality as to be useless.

Comment: @supercat the C++ language permits compilers to optimize code based on what is defined on the absrract machine, and compilers do this all the time.  From aliasing to assuming no overflow to deduced immutability.  Every.  Major.  Compiler.  Does.  This.  Your personal model of how C++ code maps to machine language is not how that code maps to machine language.  `unsigned int x=-1; int y=x;` does not give you max int on a 2s complement machine; it is UB which could be max int.  The naive machine language gives you max int, but do not let that fool you.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Describing things in terms of an abstract machine that performs operations in the indicated sequence is inferior, for programmers and compilers alike, to describing ways in which an implementation's behavior may vary from what's specified.  There are a few places where the authors of the Standard have found it necessary to take the latter approach, such as their allowance for an implementation to consolidate or omit calls to a user-supplied allocation function in certain cases.  I'd suggest such an approach is *generally* better for programmers and compilers alike...

Comment: ...than trying to formulate a sequential-execution abstract machine model.  For example, saying that operations on objects identified using different pointers or references are generally unsequenced [and may thus be arbitrarily reordered] unless they identify the same object or objects within same array of that type, but then recognizing cases where operations are sequenced, would yield a much cleaner model than pretending that each bytes of storage stores both a value and an "effective/dynamic type".

Comment: @supercat: I agree with you my friend, unfortunately it is not the way the C and C++ committees follow...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: PS--Most compilers provide options to behave more like a real machine in cases that matter--an ability which is necessary for low-level programming.  High-quality implementations configured to be suitable for low-level programming won't make programmers jump through hoops to use such abilities.  Note that the Rationale recognizes the value of having implementations extend the language by supporting behaviors which aren't explicitly required, and regards the question of when to provide such support as a Quality of Implementation issue.

Comment: Quality compilers like icc will recognize that given `float *p,*q;`, a statement like `*(uint32_t*)p += 0x00800000;` might affect `*q`, even when `-fstrict-aliasing` is enabled, because they can see that a `float*` is being used to derive a pointer which is then used to access the storage.  The Standard allows for conforming compilers that aren't suitable for low-level programming, but nothing in the Standard says that it's possible to have a *high-quality* implementation suitable for low-level programming without it being able to handle such cases.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: The Committee recognizes in the rationale that how an implementation handles cases where the Standard imposes no requirements is a Quality of Implementation issue; the Standard makes no effort to describe all the behaviors that should be expected from *good quality* implementations that claim to be *suitable for any particular purposes*. One might reasonably argue that someone without the judgment to know how such an implementation intended for some purpose should behave would be unlikely to write a quality one regardless of what the Standard says, but...

Comment: ...the language will continue to devolve unless or until there is some acknowledgement that a program's incompatibility with low-quality implementations doesn't mean it's "broken".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> int *in = reinterpret_cast<int *>(buffer); // Defined behaviour because alignment is ok
> ```

Correct. But probably not in the sense you'd expect. [[expr.static.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#13)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to `cv1 void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `cv2 T`”, where `T` is an object type and `cv2` is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, `cv1`. If the original pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` does not satisfy the alignment requirement of `T`, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object `a`, and there is an object `b` of type `T` (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with `a`, the result is a pointer to `b`. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

There is no `int` nor any pointer-interconvertible object at `buffer`, therefore the pointer value is unchanged. `in` is a pointer of type `int*` that points to a region of raw memory.

> ```
> for (int i=0; i<Size; i++) in[i] = i;  // Defined behaviour because int is a fundamental type:
>                                        // lifetime starts when is receives a value
> ```

Is incorrect. [[intro.object]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1)

> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created.

Noticeably absent is assignment. No `int` is created. In fact, by elimination, `in` is an [invalid pointer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3), and dereferencing it is UB.

The later `float*` all also follows as UB.

Even in absence of all the aforementioned UB by proper use of `new (pointer) Type{i};` to create objects, there is no *array* object in existence. The (unrelated) objects just happens to be side by side in memory. This means pointer arithmetic with the resulting pointer is also UB. [[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4)

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i+j] if 0 ≤ i+j ≤ n;` otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i−j] if 0 ≤ i−j ≤ n;` otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Where hypothetical element refers to the one past-the-end (hypothetical) element. Note that a pointer to a one past-the-end element that happens to be at the same address location as another object doesn't point to that other object.

Comment: Note that you can *mostly* fix that line with `::new( static_cast<void*>(buffer+i) ) int{i};` instead of the assignment.  There remains the "contiguous objects do not an array make" standard defect.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That sounds fun, I'll add it in.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont you mean `::new (static_cast<void*>(buffer+i*sizeof(int))) int{i}`; why not just fixing everything: `auto arr_of_int = new(buffer) int[Size];` and then use `arr_of_int[i]=a_num;` to initialize... using `static_cast<int*>(buffer)[i]=a_num` would also be UB in c++17, even if `arr_of_int` is constructed before!

Comment: Next, you can replace `void * buffer = operator new(Size * sizeof(int), alignof(int));` with a [`char * buffer = new(some_alignment_magic) char[Size*sizeof(int)];`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832358/how-to-do-c-aligned-array-allocation) and now you get an array there; it is however not an array of `int`, which leads to problems.

Comment: @Oliv Because when calling placement `new` on an array, it is not defined by the standard how many bytes you need!  (even with a fundamental type).  There are serious defects in the standard surrounding creating and managing your own arrays of any type; it is not possible to implment `std::vector` in standard C++.  This is a problem, and I don't have a solution.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'll... stop here I think.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I had forgotten this one!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So there are no good solution, because with yours, the be standard compliant, std::launder would be needed before each pointer dereferencement and at assembly level that realy causes unnecessary loads!! => I hope they'll adopt the recently C++ object model fix for C++20.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer and specifically the ref to [intro.object]. That is enough to ensure that my low level optimisation is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: @Oliv: It's too bad some compiler writers are opposed to having the Standard support code that would require `-fno-strict-aliasing` on gcc and clang, but not on higher-quality compilers like icc.  The authors of the Standard expected that compilers intended for various purposes would use UB to extend the language in ways suitable for those purposes, and there has never been any reason that a quality compiler intended for low-level programming, given the sequence `access T; convert a T* to a U*; do some stuff with a U*, access T`, not to recognize the conversion as an indication...

Comment: ...that it shouldn't consolidate preceding and following on `T` unless it can understand all intervening operations involving `U`.

Comment: @PasserBy Thank you for nice references. Could you confirm that I understood you correctly? If we add `new (buffer) int[Size]` and `new (buffer) float[Size]`,  this will make the example sane?

Comment: @Yuki Yes, provided the memory needed can be predicted, as Yakk mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Passer By's answer covers why the example program has undefined behaviour. I'll attempt to answer how to reuse storage <strike>without UB</strike> with minimal UB (reuse of storage for arrays is technically impossible in standard C++ given the current wording of the standard, so to achieve reuse, the programmer has to rely on the implementation to "do the right thing").

Converting a pointer does not automatically manifest objects into being. You have to first construct the float objects. *This* starts their lifetime and ends the lifetime of the int objects (for non-trivial objects, destructor would need to be called first):

```
for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    new(in + i) float;
```

You can use the pointer returned by placement new (which is discarded in my example) directly to use the freshly constructed `float` objects, or you can `std::launder` the `buffer` pointer:

```
float *out = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer));
```

---

However, it is  *much* more typical to reuse the storage of type `unsigned char` (or `std::byte`) rather than storage of `int` objects.

Comment: @Oliv that pointer arithmetic / array rule (quoted in Passer By's answer) is quite unfortunately worded, and I believe it is a defect in the standard. If this is interpreted to have UB because of the quoted rule, then it is impossible to implement `std::vector` using standard C++. Which is just silly in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunatly this is the case, their are a lot of discussions on SO about this subject. I had asked what was the rational for such a rule, and it seems it dives to the early day computers when appeared the first segmented memory models. Nowaday it does not make sense, and apparently the standard commitee is working to fix the oject model: [Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html)

Comment: The rational has more to do with "when is memory unreachable from a pointer".  Knowing that memory is unreachable from a given pointer makes reachability assumptions possible.  In the x86 memory model all pointers can be added/subtracted to reach any other pointer, which means that any manipulation through any pointer could cause any other value to change, which makes huge numbers of optimizations impossible; the C++ standard restrictions mean that such manipulations are UB.

Answer (score 0):

I have just popped in because it felt to me that there is at least one unanswered question, that was not spoken out loud, apologies if that is not true. I think that the guys brilliantly answered the main question of this problem: where and why it is undefined behavior; user2079303 gave few ideas how to fix it. I will try to answer the question how to fix the code and why it is valid. Before starting to read my post, please, read the answers and comment discussions under those answers of Passer By and user2079303.

Basically the issue is that objects do not exist even though they do not really need anything, except the storage, to exist. This is said in the lifetime section of the standard, however, in The C++ object model section before it is stated that

> An object is created by a definition (6.1), by a new-expression (8.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (12.3), or when a temporary object is created (7.4, 15.2).

A little bit tricky definition of object concept, but make sense. The issue is more precisely addressed in [proposal Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) to simplify the object model. Until then we should explicitly create an object by mentioned means. One of those that will work, for this case is new-placement expression, new-placement is a non-allocating new-expression, that create an object. For this particular case this will help us to crete the missing array objects and floating objects. The code below shows what I have come up with including some comments and assembly instructions associated with the lines (`clang++ -g -O0` was used).

```
constexpr int Size = 10;

void* allocate_buffer() {

  // No alignment required for the `new` operator if your object does not require
  // alignment greater than alignof(std::max_align_t), what is the case here
  void* buffer = operator new(Size * sizeof(int));
  // 400fdf:    e8 8c fd ff ff          callq  400d70 <operator new(unsigned long)@plt>
  // 400fe4:    48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)


  // (was missing) Create array of integers, default-initialized, no
  // initialization for array of integers
  new (buffer) int[Size];
  int* in = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer);
  // Two line result in a basic pointer value copy
  // 400fe8:    48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  // 400fec:    48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)


  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    in[i] = i;
  return buffer;
}

int main() {

  void* buffer = allocate_buffer();
  // 401047:    48 89 45 d0             mov    %rax,-0x30(%rbp)


  // static_cast equivalent in this case to reinterpret_cast
  int* in = static_cast<int*>(buffer);
  // Static cast results in a pointer value copy
  // 40104b:    48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  // 40104f:    48 89 45 c8             mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)


  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    std::cout << in[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), "Non matching type sizes");
  static_assert(alignof(int) == alignof(float), "Non matching alignments");
  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    int t = in[i];


    // (was missing) Create float with a direct initialization
    // Technically that is reuse of the storage of the array, hence that array does
    // not exist anymore.
    new (in + i) float{t / 2.f};
    // No new is called
    // 4010e4:  48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
    // 4010e8:  48 63 4d c0             movslq -0x40(%rbp),%rcx
    // 4010ec:  f3 0f 2a 4d bc          cvtsi2ssl -0x44(%rbp),%xmm1
    // 4010f1:  f3 0f 5e c8             divss  %xmm0,%xmm1
    // 4010f5:  f3 0f 11 0c 88          movss  %xmm1,(%rax,%rcx,4)


    // (was missing) Create int array on the same storage, default-initialized, no
    // initialization for an array of integers
    new (buffer) int[Size];
    // No code for new is generated
  }


    // (was missing) Create float array, default-initialized, no initialization for an array
    // of floats
  new (buffer) float[Size];
  float* out = reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer);
  // Two line result in a simple pointer value copy
  // 401108:    48 8b 45 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  // 40110c:    48 89 45 b0             mov    %rax,-0x50(%rbp)


  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    std::cout << out[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  operator delete(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Basically all new-placement expressions are omitted in the machine code even with `-O0`. With GCC `-O0` `operator new` is actually invoked and with `-O1` it is omitted as well. Let us forget about formalities of the standard for a second and think straight from practical sense. Why would we need to actually call the functions that are doing nothing, there is nothing that prevents it being a working without those, right? Because C++ is exactly the language where the whole control over the memory is given to the program, not to some runtime libraries or virtual machine, etc. One of the reason I might think here is that the standard again gives compilers more freedom on optimizations restricting the program to some extra action. The idea might have been that the compiler can do whatever reordering, omitting magic with the machine code knowing only definition, new-expression, union, temporary objects as new objects providers that guide the optimization algorithm. Most probably in the reality there are no such optimizations that will screw up your code if you allocated memory and did not call new operator on it for a trivial types. Interesting fact is that those non-allocating versions of `new operator` are reserved and not allowed for replacement, may be this is exactly meant to be the simplest forms telling the compiler about a new object.

Comment: A placement new a structure may only be optimized out if all parts of the resulting object are subsequently given defined values.  Otherwise, the placement new would be required to set all members of the object to default values.  Requiring the use of placement new on structures in cases where some fields' values will never be used would thus compel the generation of inefficient code.  While it's possible that some institutional programming standards might forbid returning partially-initialized objects, there's no reason the language as a whole should be interpreted as doing so.

Comment: It might be reasonable for a quality implementation that is intended to prevent information leaks to squawk if code re-purposes a region of storage without overwriting everything therein, but a quality implementation that is intended to allow programmers to write maximally-efficient code should allow the use of more efficient constructs (e.g. leaving unused members uninitialized).  The Standard allows low-quality implementations to be "conforming" while being useless, quality implementations should make reasonable effort to behave usefully whether or not they're required to do so.

Comment: @supercat We have to have some standardization, some rule book to guide the implementation, otherwise every implementation will diverge from each other and we will have different languages, or there will have to be only one implementation that is a standard, right? Sometimes somewhere the wording of this abstract document will be wrong, but overall value of it is still hight.

Comment: @supercat "Requiring the use of placement new on structures in cases where some fields' values will never be used would thus compel the generation of inefficient code" - that is not necessarily true, unused initialization instruction also could be optimized out, right?

Comment: @supercat If we talk about trivial type or array of trivial type objects, then I totally agree that should be fixed in the standard as it said in proposal Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation. That will make the code and the language more simple and intuitive. For now, I have shown the code that conform to the standard and does not lose performance.

Comment: If the compiler can see that some bytes written by default initialization get overwritten, it can skip the earlier writes.  If it can see that an object gets destroyed without certain bytes ever having been read, it can omit any writes to those bytes.  In the hardly-uncommon case where a function gives an object to outside code without having written all of the bytes after default initialization, however, the compiler would be required to perform the default initialization even if, in fact, none of the outside code would care.

Comment: The semantically-proper time to implicitly create objects is when pointers or references to them are created, with an allowance for two special situations: (1) multiple objects may use the same storage if the object is not modified while such a situation exists [conceptually similar to a compiler storing string literals "tango" and "go" using overlapping storage], and (2) if an object is used to derive a pointer or reference to a different object using the same storage, and the latter ceases to exist while storage is still available, the former object will again become available.

Comment: (As a point of clarification, an object would generally cease to exist in the absence of any existing references or pointers that will ever be used to access it or derive other pointers/objects that will be thus used).  The primary reason the "aliasing" rules exist is to indicate when compilers need to make allowances for references that unexpectedly identify the same object, but no allowances are required in cases where storage is not modified, and an object which is visibly derived from another can hardly be said to "unexpectedly" alias it in the context of such derivation.